# Allow access for localhost and named server

Tags: mysql, security, configuration

I'm trying to set up a user to allow them access from localhost and from a specific named server. Is this possible in MySQL and if it is how do I do it?

I know I can use `%` under the host to allow access from any server, but I'm looking to limit the access to let's say `localhost` and `testserver1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'ip_testserver1', 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Of course, feel free to replace the `ALL PRIVILEGES` by the rights you want to allow to your user, and the `*.*` with the database name & tables name.